# Element (VueJS) | Conditional table rendering

Tags: vue.js, element, axios

The question is about VueJS Framework - Element: http://element.eleme.io

I have some table (el-table) who gets data from array:

```
<el-table :data="someData">
<el-table-column prop="id" label="№"></el-table-column>
<el-table-column prop="is_active" label="Active"></el-table-column>
</el-table>
```

axios get JSON from DB, the array looks like:

```
[
{
  "id":1,
  "is_active":0
},
{
  "id":2,
  "is_active":1
},{
  "id":3,
  "is_active":1
}
]
```

Anyone knows how to say Element table show only rows with property "is_active" eq 0 or 1 (or another condition)?

Comment: Why not filter the data before passing it to the component, e.g. using a computed property?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a [computed property](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html) filtering your array, such as :

```
computed: {
  filteredList() {
    if (this.someData) {
      return this.someData.filter(data => data && data.is_active);
    }
    return [];
  },
},
```

And then bind this filtered list to the component :

```
<el-table :data="filteredList">
```

Comment: It should probably be `if (this.someData && this.someData.length)` in case `someData` has an initial value of `[]`.

Comment: The `filter` method simply returns an empty array if the initial array is empty.

Comment: But it won't have to trigger `array.filter()`.

Comment: You're right ! Sorry I didn't get your point in the first place.